# Django extra_views, ModelFormSetView doesn't save the data

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have two problems, i have a flat table with settings in my db, structure is:
setting: char
value: char

It shows the form just fine, but:

**First Problem**: It shows an empty field combination at the end.

**Second problem**: It doesn't save the data, no error, no redirect to the success page, nothing.

my views.py:

```
class UpdateSettings(ModelFormSetView):
    model = Settings
    fields = ['setting', 'value']
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    success_url = '/shows'
```

my settings.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">            
                    {{ form.setting|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">            
                    {{ form.value|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-group form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Change</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem: By default the django modelformset_factory (which the view uses in the background) creates one extra empty form. To avoid this add the factory_kwargs to your view

```
class UpdateSettings(ModelFormSetView):
    model = Settings
    fields = ['setting', 'value']
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    success_url = '/shows'
    factory_kwargs = {'extra': 0}
```

Your second problem: I saw the formset is throwing an error because the 'id' field is required. Add the 'id' to your template:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-6">
       {{ form.id }}            
       {{ form.setting|as_crispy_field }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">            
      {{ form.value|as_crispy_field }}
   </div>
</div>
```

i don't think 'id' needs to be added to the 'fields' in your view as it is added by default